# How to make component appear/disappear animation in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a block of content:

```
<div className="col-7">
    {content}
</div>
```

A component is placed in "content" depending on the state:

```
switch (activeItem) {
    case "home": {
        content = <AppHome/>
        break;
    }
    case "about-me": {
        content = <AppAboutMe/>
        break;
    }
    default:
        content = null
}
```

How to add content change animation so that one disappears smoothly, the other appears?

I tried to add animation through CSS class. It worked, but the disappearance was interrupted by the appearance. I tried through CSS transition but it appeared only once and did not disappear. When the content was subsequently changed, the animations no longer worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little **[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/animation-w-framer-p84wh4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=preview)** project I made to refer as an example:

To handle animation among several components, I recommend having all of your available components in a single constant. For example:

```js
const components = {
  title: {
    key: '1',
    content: <div>New York</div>,
  },
  body: {
    key: '2',
    content: (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>cheese</li>
          <li>tomato</li>
          <li>onions</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    ),
  },
};
```

And then you can initialise your state with the wanted ones.

```js
const [fields, setFields] = useState([]); // [] || [components.title]
```

Then, depending on your logic you can either add components on top of existing ones or remove by setting your state.

```js
const onEnter = () => {
    setFields([...fields, components.title]);
  };
const onExit = () => {
  setFields([]);
};
```

Lastly, in order to animate state changes, you can wrap your components with `<motion.div>{component}<motion.div/>`, setting variants will take care of the details of your animation process.